# Execute an "or statement" in return in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple code:

```
    var lmao = this.state.items.taxonomies.filter((item) => {
        return item.slug === "hello"
    })
```

What I want to happen is something like this:

```
    var lmao = this.state.items.taxonomies.filter((item) => {
        return item.slug === "hello" || "hi";
    })
```

I want to use the `or` operator indicating that the value of `lmao` can have the slug value of either `"hello"` or `"hi"` but it doesn't seem to work. What is the proper syntax? do I have to create an if statement or a switch case?

Comment: `item.slug === "hello" || item.slug === "hi"` or `["hello","hi"].includes(item.slug)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using -> item.slug === "hello" || "hi", indicates that you are comparing slug value to "hello", if it matches it returns true  else it returns "hi", which is by default true (as it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value), which is not what you intended. You can change to below code to what you exactly need

```
var lmao = this.state.items.taxonomies.filter((item) => {
        return item.slug === "hello" || item.slug === "hi";
    })
```